# Get count of rows and group by subfolder using python

Tags: python

I have 3 sub folders which contain multiple csv files.I want to show record count of all the files grouped by sub folders

I have a code which gives me count of a single file only

```
with open (r"c:\users\doc\file.csv",'r') as fp:
   lines=len(fp.readlines())
   print('total lines:', lines)`
```

Expected output:

```
Foldername Count

Product1 -53000321

Product2- 1245

Product3- 162
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be first to get list of subfolders, then traverse each to find files and add to list/touple.

```
import os
d  = r'.' #set to your path where subfolders are
result =[] #this will be used to store results

#get list of subfolders
subdirs = [os.path.join(d, o) for o in os.listdir(d) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d,o))]

for fld in subdirs: #iterate subfolders
    files = os.listdir(fld)
    files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(fld+'/'+f)] #Filtering only the files.
    for f in files: #iterate files
        #if needed to filter by filename or extension, add here
        with open(fld+'/'+f,'r') as fp:
            lines=len(fp.readlines())
            result.append({'Foldername': os.path.basename(fld), 'Count':lines})
            #basename gives last folder name from path
```

Output #in result

| Foldername | Count |
| --- | --- |
| fld1 | 123 |
| fld3 | 456 |

Comment: for lines, I have to use readlines function ?

Comment: lines refer to readlines fn

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi @bracko,Thanks for your time , your code is working,However, it is repeating and is not aggregating,Suppose there are 3 files in fld1, then it shows 3 rows for fld1 and shows rows for that 3 files.

Comment: Aha, then lets use group by on result. 
`code`  
#load into pandas data frame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
agg = df.groupby('Foldername').sum() `code` 
See more at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Hi @bracko, There is 1 issue with the above code, If there is another subfolder in a subfolder than this subfolder is ignored and it's files are not counted.